# refreshing keycloak access token gives ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am trying to use a refresh token from keycloak. I can use the original access token via curl and receive data from my application. But when It try to get a new access token using my refresh token,

```
$ curl -v --data "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=bikes-app&refresh_token=$RTOKEN" https://mint191:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mint191 (127.0.1.1) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

$ echo $RTOKEN
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUI......A8dS93p6bzqg

I get the original token with

> RESULT=`curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d
>   'username=user1&grant_type=password&client_id=bikes-app&password=123456'
>   http://mint191:8080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token`

and then get the token and refresh token variables. I can then use the token to access data from the application.

Just to add, I am not behind a proxy (which seems to be the cause in other examples of this on stackoverflow). If I can get an access and refresh token, then I should be able to use a refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake on my part.

I was calling for the refresh token on https rather than http.